# R epiDisplay package and other epidemiology packages not working with survey weighted glm?

Tags: r, glm, survey

I'm using R Studio and have data from a survey that uses strata, weights, and nesting. Accordingly, I have used the `library(survey)` to set up a svydesign and then used svyglm to complete the desired logistic regression using said svydesign (saved as output2).

When I try to use the `library(epiDisplay)` or any of the other epidemiological packages on R, I get the following error:

> logistic.display(output2) 
>   Error in logistic.display(output2) : Model not from logistic regression

The package works correctly for regression results that used glm, but not svyglm. How do I incorporate my survey design and still get epidemiological results? Is there a package available that can do both?

### Edit

An example with free data (purely for example purposes): NHANES 2011-2012 Brominated Flame Retardants (BFRs) - Serum - Pooled Samples (BFRPOL_G).

It's available for download here: https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2011-2012/BFRPOL_G.XPT

After download, set library(survey), and create

```
    BROM <- svydesign(id =new$SDMVPSU, strata = new$SDMVSTRA, weights = 
    new$WTSMSMPA, nest = TRUE, data = BFRPOL_G)
```

Now (a meaningless) regression, but it nonetheless demonstrates the problem:

```
output2<-svyglm(RIAGENDR~RIGAGGRP+LBDBR66C, family = binomial, data=BFRPOL_G, design = BROM, maxit=100)

library(epiDisplay)
logistic.display(output2)
```

The result?

```
> logistic.display(output2)
> Error in logistic.display(output2) : Model not from logistic regression
```

There is another Stack Exchange question/answer over here (bottom of page provided by Edward): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/logistic-regression-in-r-odds-ratio that shows how concisely the epiDesign package can display results.

With a logistic regression, it can provide crude OR & 95% CI, adjusted OR & 95% CI, Wald's Test, and LR's test. It also shows the number of observations and the AIC.

I don't know how to get all of that information out of my regression without this package. There are other epidemiological libraries, but I don't know of one that that allows me to incorporate the survey weight/design.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Also, please include some sample data using `dput()`.

Comment: I've provided a link to free sample data that will recreate the problem. I'm not sure what dput() is in this context, but the regression, though scientifically meaningless, will show you what I mean about the regression results.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside `logistic.display` has

```
    if (length(class(model)) == 1) {
        stop("Model not from logistic regression")
    }
    if (class(model)[1] != "glm" | class(model)[2] != "lm" | 
        model$family$family != "binomial") {
        stop("Model not from logistic regression")
    }
```

so it's deliberately excluding objects that just inherit from `glm`.  You might have to contact the `epiDisplay` package author -- it could be that the function intrinsically can't work on logistic regressions with sampling weights, or it could be that the author was just not imaginative enough.